# ERROR 1045: Transferring SQL database from one server to another

Tags: mysql, sql, transfer

I have taken the the following steps to transfer my sql database but yet I receive an error on the importing of the database onto the new server. It does not seem to recognize my username or password.

I think the problem is being caused by phpMyAdmin privilege settings. I am transferring my sql file from a server that runs phpMyAdmin (hostgator) to an unmanaged web server.

Here are the steps I took

```
mysqldump -u root_wrdp1 -p --opt root_wrdp1 > root_wrdp1.sql
Enter password:
```

I then scp'd the sql file to my new web server (that does not run phpMyAdmin).

```
scp rbl91_wrdp1.sql root@ip.of.the.server:~/
```

Then I did the updating of the database on the web server without phpmyadmin...

```
root@www:~# mysql -u root_wrdp1 -p root_wrdp1 < ~/root_wrdp1.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root_wprd1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The support by the site offered this advice but I have no idea how to implement the steps.

> It's possible you have to review the authorization locations, such as the source location (IP) of the remote side.
>
> Using phpMyAdmin i believe the page is Priviliages , and you will also
>   need to flush them after changing.
>
> Thanks Support

Comment: I would suggest you to move this query to DB forum.

Comment: This has nothing to do with transferring a database between sites. It's a simple user authentication error on the new site. Make sure you have the correct username and password in order to access the new database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple authentication problem. Most likely the "root_wrp1" account or password are set up incorrectly on the destination machine. You can check it just by trying to log in without importing the dump file:

```
$ mysql -u root_wrdp1 -p root_wrdp1
```

The account and password need to be set up and have adequate permissions to the database before you can restore the dump file.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the problem. For future references of those who have the same problem, you must have the same corresponding username and password of the account from the original server on the server you wish to transfer to. I'm a newbie to mysql and was not aware of this. +1